# Find multiple controls by tag

Tags: c#, winforms

Pretty new to C#, I'm working on a WinForms app (a small game), where I want several Picture Boxes to act the same (not all of them, though). From looking around online, I figured the quickest way would be to use tags and my initial idea, based on what I've found, is to put them under something like this:

```
foreach (??? pb in ???.Find???WithTag("enemy"))
```

My question is, what should go in place of "???"? Visual Studio accepts neither "FindPictureBoxWithTag" nor "FindPictureBoxesWithTag".

Comment: A container `Control` has a `Controls` property you can iterate over to find its direct descendants. Anyway WinForms is an UI framework. You should not bind your game logic to your UI. The UI should merely _represent_ a state that you calculate in your business logic. You tie the UI to your BL using events and data binding. But I suppose that's a bit too much to grasp when just starting out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(p=>p.Tag == "enemy")
{
}
```

Replace `this.Controls` with any collection/container that contains the picture boxes